# performance impact, if a class have all synchronized methods?

Tags: java

I want to create a class where all methods will be thread safe (synchronized methods).

Is there any performance impact with this approach?

If yes then what approach I should follow?

Comment: Please try some effort by reading javadoc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any performance impact with this approach?

Definitely yes as one thread has to wait if other has already entered under synchronized method

> If yes then what approach I should use?

It depends what you want to achieve. If really you need to synchronization then its fine. Would recommend to explore synchronized blocks as you can limit the scope of synchronization. Other way to look for is java concurrent package which provides you the lock object providing more control but also involves overhead of managing it.

Comment: Thanks M Sach. I will explore more synchronized blocks and java concurrent package.